# How to add a custom position inside a forEach loop for each Canvas DrawImage?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to display multiple images using Canvas DrawImages with each a unique position. I have created an array with multiple images and I would like to position them on different parts of the canvas on load.

Now, all the canvas images are stacked on each other.

This is my JS:

```
(() => {
    // Canvas Setup
    let canvas = document.getElementById('hedoneCanvas');
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // // Canvas Images
    let imageSources = [
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1313267/pexels-photo-1313267.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=food-fruit-green-1313267.jpg&fm=jpg',
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2965413/pexels-photo-2965413.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2196602/pexels-photo-2196602.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
        'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2955490/pexels-photo-2955490.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'
    ];

    // Canvas Size
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    const loadImage = imagePath => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener('load', () => {
                resolve(image);
            });
            image.addEventListener('error', err => {
                reject(err);
            });
            image.src = imagePath;
        });
    };

    const canvasOnResize = () => {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight;
    };

    window.addEventListener('resize', canvasOnResize);

    Promise.all(imageSources.map(i => loadImage(i)))
        .then(images => {
            images.forEach(image => {
                console.log(context);
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
})();
```

I also want to make them responsive how can I archive this?

I have demo on Codepen: **https://codepen.io/Merdzanovich/pen/dybLQqL**

Trying to do something like this on hover: 
**http://vlnc.studio/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Responsive `canvas`

To make the content of a canvas responsive it is best to use a reference display size. This represents the ideal display size that your content is viewed in.

The reference is used to then calculate how to display the content on displays that do not match the ideal size.

In the example below the object `reference` defines the reference display and provides methods to resize the canvas and scale and position the content.

With the reference defined you can then position and size your content for the reference display.

For example the constant `imageMaxSize = 512` sets the max size (width or height) of an image. The 512 is relative to the reference display (1920, 1080). The actual size that the image is display depends on the size of the page.

It sets a matrix that is used to transform the content to fit the display. Rather then use the top left of the display as origin (0,0) it sets the center of the canvas as the origin.

The example lets you set how the canvas responds to the display resolution, the const `scaleMethod` can be set to

- `"fit"` will ensure that all the content will be displayed (as long as it fits the reference). However there may be blank areas above below or left and right of the content if the display aspect is different from the reference.
- `"fill"` will ensure that the content will fill the display. However some of the content (top and bottom, or left and right) may be clipped if the display aspect does not match the reference.

### Positioning images.

That just requires an array that holds the image position and size relative to the reference display.

In the example the array `displayList` which extends an array has the function

- `add(image,x,y)` that adds an image to the list. The x and y represent the position of the image center and is relative to the reference display origin (center of canvas)

  When an images is added its reference size is calculated from its natural size
- `draw(ctx)` will draw all the items in the display list using the reference matrix to scale and position the images.

### Rendering

Rather than render to the canvas ad-hock a render loop is used `updateCanvas` that ensures content is updated in sync with the display hardware. The ensure that if you have animated content it does not produce artifacts (shearing, flicker)

To prevent the rendering to needlessly draw content the render loop will only render the content when the semaphore `update` is set to `true`. For example when resizing the canvas the content needs to be rendered. This is achieved by simply setting `update=true`

Rather than use the resize event to resize the canvas, the render loop checks if the canvas size matches the page size. If there is a miss match then the canvas is resize. this is done because the resize event is not synced with the display hardware and will cause poor quality rendering while the display is being resized. it also ensures that the canvas is not resized more than once between display frames.

### Example

```js
requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const SCALE_METHOD = "fit";
const images = [];
const ALPHA_FADE_IN_SPEED = 0.04;  // for fade in out approx time  use
                                   // seconds = (0.016666 / ALPHA_FADE_IN_SPEED) 
const FADE_OVERLAP = 0.4;          // fraction of fade time. NOT less or equal to
                                   // ALPHA_FADE_IN_SPEED and not greater equal to 0.5
const IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 480;        // image isze in pixel of reference display
const IMAGE_MIN_SIZE = IMAGE_MAX_SIZE * 0.8;
const IMAGE_SCALE_FLICK = IMAGE_MAX_SIZE * 0.05;
// sigmoid curve return val 0-1. P is power. 
//   0 < p < 1 curve eases center
//   1 == p    linear curve
//   1 < p     curve eases out from 0 and into 1
Math.sCurve = (u, p = 2) =>  u <= 0 ? 0 : u >= 1 ? 1 : u ** p / (u ** p + (1 - u) ** p); 

// Simple spring
//   constructor(u,[a,[d,[t]]])
//     u is spring position
//     a is acceleration default 0.1
//     d is dampening default 0.9
//     t is spring target (equalibrium) default t = u
//   properties
//     u current spring length
//     flick(v) // adds movement to spring
//     step(u) gets next value of spring. target defaults to this.target
Math.freeSpring = (u, a = 0.3 , d = 0.65, t = u) => ({
    u,
    v : 0,
    set target(v) { t = v },
    flick(v) { this.v = v * (1/d) *(1/a)},
    step(u = t) { return this.u += (this.v = (this.v += (u - this.u) * a) * d) }
})

var update = false;

const reference = {
  get width() { return 1920 },  // ideal display resolution
  get height() { return 1080 },
  matrix: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  resize(method, width = innerWidth, height = innerHeight) {
    method = method.toLowerCase();
    var scale = 1; // one to one of reference
    if (method === "fit") {
      scale = Math.min(width / reference.width, height / reference.height);
    } else if (method === "fill") {
      scale = Math.max(width / reference.width, height / reference.height);
    }
    const mat = reference.matrix;
    mat[3] = mat[0] = scale;
    mat[4] = width / 2;
    mat[5] = height / 2;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    update = true;
  },
  checkSize() {
    if (canvas.width !== innerWidth || canvas.height !== innerHeight) {
      reference.resize(SCALE_METHOD);
    }
  },
};


{
  let count = 0;
  [
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1313267/pexels-photo-1313267.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=food-fruit-green-1313267.jpg&fm=jpg',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2965413/pexels-photo-2965413.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2196602/pexels-photo-2196602.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/2955490/pexels-photo-2955490.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'
  ].forEach(src => {
    count++;
    const img = new Image;
    img.src = src;
    img.addEventListener("load", () => {
      images.push(img);
      if (! --count) { setup() }
    })
    img.addEventListener("error", () => {if (! --count) { setup() }});
  });
}
const displayList = Object.assign([], {
  add(image, x, y) { 
    var item;
    var w = image.naturalWidth;
    var h = image.naturalHeight;
    const scale = Math.min(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / w, IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / h);
    w *= scale;
    h *= scale;
    displayList.push(item = {
        image, x, y, w, h, 
        fading: false, 
        alpha: 0, 
        alphaStep: 0, 
        onAlphaReady: undefined, 
        scaleFX: Math.freeSpring(IMAGE_MIN_SIZE)
    });
    displayList.fadeQueue.push(item);
    return item;
  },
  fadeQueue: [],
  draw(ctx) {
    var curvePower = 2
    ctx.setTransform(...reference.matrix);
    for (const item of displayList) {
      if (item.fading) {
         item.alpha += item.alphaStep;
         curvePower = item.alphaStep > 0 ? 2 : 2;         
         if (item.onAlphaReady && (
             (item.alphaStep < 0 && item.alpha <= FADE_OVERLAP) || 
             (item.alphaStep > 0 && item.alpha >= 1 - FADE_OVERLAP))) {
              item.onAlphaReady(item);          
              item.onAlphaReady = undefined;
         } else if (item.alpha <= 0 || item.alpha >= 1) {
            item.fading = false;
         }
                
         update = true;
      }
      ctx.globalAlpha = Math.sCurve(item.alpha, curvePower);
      const s =  item.scaleFX.step() / IMAGE_MAX_SIZE; 
      ctx.drawImage(item.image, item.x - item.w / 2 * s, item.y - item.h / 2 * s, item.w * s, item.h * s);
    }
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // default transform
  }
});

function fadeNextImage() {
  const next = displayList.fadeQueue.shift();
  if(next.alpha < 0.5) { // Start fade in
    next.scaleFX.flick(IMAGE_SCALE_FLICK);
    next.scaleFX.target = IMAGE_MAX_SIZE;
    next.alphaStep = ALPHA_FADE_IN_SPEED;    
  } else {  // Start fade out
    next.scaleFX.flick(IMAGE_SCALE_FLICK); 
    next.scaleFX.target = IMAGE_MIN_SIZE;    
    next.alphaStep = -ALPHA_FADE_IN_SPEED;    
  }
  next.onAlphaReady = fadeNextImage;
  next.fading = true;
  displayList.fadeQueue.push(next);
}
function setup() {
  const repeat = 2;
  var i, len = images.length;
  const distX = (reference.width - IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) * 0.45;
  const distY = (reference.height - IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) * 0.45;
  for (i = 0; i < len * repeat; i++) {  
    const ang = i / (len * repeat) * Math.PI * 2 - Math.PI / 2;
    displayList.add(images[i % len],  Math.cos(ang) * distX, Math.sin(ang) * distY);
  }
  fadeNextImage();
}
function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
}
function loading(time) {
  clearCanvas();
  ctx.font = "12px arial";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,ctx.canvas.width / 2, ctx.canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.fillText("loading",0,0);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  const pos = time + Math.cos(time) * 0.25 + 1;
  ctx.arc(0 ,0, 24, pos, pos + Math.cos(time * 0.1) * 0.5 + 1);
  ctx.stroke();
}
  

function updateCanvas(time) {
  reference.checkSize()
  if(!displayList.length) {
    loading(time / 100);
  
  } else if (update) {
    update = false;
    clearCanvas();
    displayList.draw(ctx);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(updateCanvas);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Very bad idea to keep an ever running animation loop, you will force the browser to enter the [update the rendering](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) steps at every painting frames, and this for no good reasons at all. If you read there, the fifth point is "run the resize steps". Window `resize` event **is already in sync with the display rate**.

Comment: How do I add an opacity with your code from 0 to 1 for each image? @Blindman67

Comment: @Galanthus use the 2D context property `ctx.globalAlpha` with values 0 to 1. I have added some code to the example adding FXs to the images including a fade in and out using  `ctx.globalAlpha`

Comment: @Blinman67 thank you very much. I want all images to be opacity 0 and only on hover opacity 1 like example from here: http://vlnc.studio/ how can i archive this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Promise.all(imageSources.map(i => loadImage(i)))
    .then(images => {
        images.forEach((image,key) => {
            context.drawImage(image, key*100, key*100, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```